# Why to_categorical() in Keras uses float64 instead of float32?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

Per my test, `to_categorical()` in Keras returns an `ndarray` of `float64`. I'm wondering why it is not `float32` by default, which can be processed by GPU. As far as I know, GPU cannot deal with `float64`. The [documentation](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical) of `to_categorical()` doesn't state what the return type should be. So, I guess it may be an implementation detail, and not part of the protocol/interface. To summarize, two questions:

1. Why `float64` and not `float32`?
2. Should the return type not be relied on, since it may not be part of the interface, and is thus subject to change? If it's the case, an `astype()` call should always be appended if the type is cared about.

Comment: If you're feeding the output of `to_categorical()` directly to the model, then it shouldn't affect much. This array will always be converted to the data type of model's output tensor when being used in `fit`. Under normal usage, this data type would be `K.floatx()`, which is `'float32'` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The problem lies in `numpy.zeros` function [used](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/np_utils.py#L30) in `to_categorical`. As a default, it creates an array of type `float64`.
2. Unfortunately, I'd advice you to test your solution to such issues as currently no consistency in data types are guaranteed. Usually - most of the transformers return data in a provided format so as long your base data is in `float32` - it will stay `float32`. But there are some edge cases like `to_categorical`.

In my projects I'm using `docker` in order to keep things consistent across all of the machines I use for training/inference.